# Show an alert if the entered credentials are wrong in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire, alert

when I input wrong username or password my application got hang
I want to show an alert when input entered is wrong here is how I'm trying

```
switch response.result {
                case .success:
                    
                    let responseData = response.value as? NSDictionary
```

// Error on next line is **Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

```
                    let successDic: NSDictionary = responseData?.value(forKey: "success") as! NSDictionary 

                    let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homeVC") as? HomeVC
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
                    break
```

In case of failure the control of program is not coming here instead it goes into the success case and show an error which I have mentioned

```
                    case .failure:
                        self.ShowAlert(title: "Warning", message: "Please enter valid credentials")
                    break
            }
```

Comment: can you add the `responseData` in question, it might not be an NSDictionary as the casting fails.

Comment: it always will be in failure when no internet or such cases, when you got a response from the server it will be always in success and you have to handle your data and show the error coming in the server response.